# GitLab CI/CD jekyll build fails when cache is enabled

Tags: jekyll, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I working on a GitLab CI/CD pipeline to build and deploy a jekyll website. The following setup is working when I don't have the cache activated.

```
image: ruby:2.6

# Cache gems in between builds
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - vendor/ruby

before_script:
  - gem install bundler
  #- ruby -v                      # Print out ruby version for debugging
  #- apt-get update -q && apt-get install nodejs -yqq
  #- bundle install --path vendor # Install dependencies into ./vendor/ruby
  - bundle install

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - bundle exec jekyll build -d public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
  - develop

master-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    # Install ssh client
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install openssh-client

    # Set up keys
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

    # Set up known hosts
    - echo "$KNOWN_HOST" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

  script:
    # Install rsync
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y rsync  

    # Transfer files
    ...

    # Backup old versions
    ...

  only:
    - master

develop-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    # Install ssh client
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install openssh-client

    # Set up keys
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

    # Set up known hosts
    - echo "$KNOWN_HOST" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

  script:
    # Install rsync
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y rsync  

    # Transfer files
    ...

    # Backup old version
    ...

  only:
    - develop
```

As soon I activate the cache `build install --path vendor` then I get the following error:

```
Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 8): Unknown tag 'when' in vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/locales/en.yml
jekyll 3.8.6 | Error:  Liquid syntax error (line 8): Unknown tag 'when'
```

I already deleted the cache on GitLab (CI/CD->Pipelines->Clear runner cache) without any success. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you talking about your cache in you `before_script` command ? when do you try to execute `build install --path vendor` ?

Comment: Do you really need `bundle install --path vendor` ? You can try `bundle exec jekyll build -d public --trace` to have some more clues.

Comment: I would be nice if `bunde install --path vendor` would work as it wouldn't have to install all the packages on every run.